# Where is the PHP API for uploading MWS Order Confirmations?

Tags: amazon-mws

I want to upload order confirmations to MWS. I have the flat file template. I need the actual PHP code library that makes the confirmation possible.

I have used the PHP API that MWS provides to handle products and orders. I just don't know where to find the Order Confirmation api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide shipment confirmations to Amazon, you need to use the **[SubmitFeed](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html#Feeds_SubmitFeed)** operation in the Amazon MWS API with the `_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_` [FeedType](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html).

For an example of how to do this in PHP, you should download the [sample PHP client library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html) and refer to the file named `SubmitFeedSample.php`.